# Null pointer location with health monitoring in asp net

Tags: asp.net, health-monitoring

I'm working on an asp net application and have enabled health Monitoring in my config

after a null pointer exception i get an error mail receiving the details of the exception with the information of the class and method in which the exception occurred.Is there any way to get the exact number of the line where this exception happened in the method ?

Comment: it should be included as part of the stack trace if it was available in the original stack trace. Was there a stacktrace in the email?